# UnitTest a function with a DbContext as parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, nunit, dbcontext

**Hey I'm try to test this Function.**

**Edit:**

**The goal is to write a test that checks if the *validate* function works correct.**

I'm just start with unit testing.

I already tried just to mock the Context but this is not the solution.

It is not working or I made something wrong. ( Connection String error )

**What is the correct approach for this Problem ?**

Do you have any Idea ?

Thanks for your help.

```cs
public static string validate(ProductDBEntities _db)
        {
            List<string> errorList = new List<string>();


            foreach (var error in _db.GetValidationErrors())
            {
                errorList.Add(error.ValidationErrors.FirstOrDefault().ErrorMessage);
            }

            if (errorList.Count > 0)
            {
                string errors = string.Join("\n", errorList);
                return errors;
            }
            return "";
        }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to mock here? To mock a type you need to define what your methods should return in case someone uses them. I can´t see any code for this nor can´t I see any UnitTest-code.

Comment: thanks for quick reply. Ok I understand to mock is not the right way. But what should I do to test this function?

Comment: I suppose it *is*, however be aware that you can only mock for interfaces and abstract classes or classes that have virtual members. In your case if you want to substitute the call to `_db.GetValidationErrors` which I suppose you want this method has to be `virtual` in `ProductDBEntities`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution to be able to unit test the logic inside validate would probably be:

```
public static string validate(List<SomeErrorMessageThing> validationErrors) //Whatever type var error is
        {
            List<string> errorList = new List<string>();

            foreach (SomeErrorMessageThing error in validationErrors)
            {
                errorList.Add(error.ValidationErrors.FirstOrDefault().ErrorMessage);
            }

            if (errorList.Count > 0)
            {
                string errors = string.Join("\n", errorList);
                return errors;
            }
            return "";
        }
```

Then you don't have to mock anything, you could just send inn your manually crafted list of validationErrors from your test